# Getting nulls in task when calling method shows non-empty string

Tags: c#, concurrency

I've got some code that parses a CSV, it's meant to fire off tasks and process the records in batches. I have some type of concurrency issue where I'm getting a null string passed into `SplitCsvLineToCells`. The crazy thing is, when I migrate up the call stack in visual studio, I can see the array index/string that's passed in, and it's not null! Is it possible I'm hitting garbage collection and losing the string reference? I'm drawing a bit of a blank at this point. None of the strings passed in should ever be null (based on the input, strings are definitely all populated). Here's the code:

```
    static SemaphoreSlim semaphore;
    static MemoryStream outputStream;
    static StreamWriter writer;
    static StreamReader reader;
    static string[] headers;
    static int readCount = 0;
    static int BATCH_SIZE = 25;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = args[0];
        semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(Environment.ProcessorCount);

        var csv = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        outputStream = new MemoryStream();
        writer = new StreamWriter(outputStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        reader = new StreamReader(csv, Encoding.UTF8);
        headers = SplitCsvLineToCells(reader.ReadLine());
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        var lines = new string[BATCH_SIZE];
        var currentIndex = 0;
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            lines[currentIndex] = reader.ReadLine();
            currentIndex++;
            readCount++;

            if (readCount % BATCH_SIZE == 0)
            {
                semaphore.Wait();
                var task = new Task(() => ProcessRecords(lines));
                task.Start();
                tasks.Add(task);
                lines = new string[BATCH_SIZE];
                currentIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("complete.");
    }

    static void ProcessRecords(string[] lines)
    {
        try
        {
            var uploads = new List<Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>>();
            for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] parsedLine = SplitCsvLineToCells(lines[i]); // in the debugger when moving up the call stack, lines[i] is not null.
                var outputObject = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>();
                for (var j = 0; j < headers.Length && j < parsedLine.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parsedLine[j]))
                        outputObject.Add(headers[j], new AttributeValue() { S = parsedLine[j] == "" ? null : parsedLine[j] });
                }
                uploads.Add(outputObject);
            }
            // GO DO MORE STUFF HERE
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processing failed: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    static string[] SplitCsvLineToCells(string line, char delimeter = ',') 
    {
        // the line in here shows as null
        // but in the debugger the calling function string isn't null
    }
```

Comment: One unrelated observation: You instantiate several things that implement IDisposable. Use the using keyword to ensure they are property cleaned up.

Comment: You'll also miss lines at the end of the file unless the number of lines is exactly divisible by BATCH_SIZE.

Comment: @EricJ. I'm aware of the hanging records I'll miss & the lack of dispose calls. I was trying to produce a minimum example so I cut out a lot of code.

Comment: It also looks like you'll miss the last item on the line. For example if the line contains a single item then this won't find it. You really should use a package like [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) or [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Comment: @JimMischel The CSV parsers I tried using were either too slow or allocated too many objects. In general I would agree with you but memory overhead is important for this application. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: The only way I see that a `null` could be passed to your CSV parser is if the `lines` array you passed to `ProcessRecords` wasn't a full batch. Debugging multithreaded programs can be tricky sometimes. Is it possible that the `lines` array you looked at was actually the array for a different thread?

Comment: @JimMischel It's entirely possible, I was just viewing it via Visual Studio's standard call stack window. I don't know if the call stack window honors the thread hit by a conditional breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

The way you want to approach this problem is to create a small number of persistent tasks that read from a single queue that is designed for multiple producers and consumers. Something like this:

```
// The queue, initialized with a maximum capacity of 25 lines.
// Increase or decrease depending on your needs.
private BlockingCollection<string> linesQueue = new BlockingCollection<string>(25);

// in your Main

var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessLines, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessLines, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);


// The producer reads lines and adds them to the queue
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(inputFilename))
{
    linesQueue.Add(line);
}

// Tell the queue that no more data is forthcoming.
linesQueue.CompleteAdding();

// wait for the consumers to complete
task1.Wait();
task2.Wait();

// and your ProcessRecords method
void ProcessRecords()
{
    // do whatever initialization you want here
    foreach (var line in linesQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        // split the line and do what you want with the result
    }
}
```

This structure is simple, proven, and effective. It's also flexible in that you can have as many producers and consumers as you like. It uses persistent threads rather that spawning a new thread for every small batch, which causes you to lose some performance due to thread startup overhead.

If your processing threads need to output to a common place, you can create a separate output queue (another `BlockingCollection`) that the threads write to, and another persistent task that reads the queue and writes the data to file.

For more information about how all this works, see my blog post, [Simple multithreading, Part 2](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/07/18/simple-multithreading-part-2/).

Comment: Where do I ever read/write from a List at the same time? The main thread populates an array, passes it to a task and then discards it. From that point on (in `ProcessRecords` and `SplitCsvLineToCells` everything occurs on a single thread.

I like the approach you've laid out so I'll give it a try, but I'm still not understanding exactly where in my code the problem occurs.